# Static file does not work: Not Found: /{static 'logo.png'}

Tags: python, django

In my Django app I created a navbar.
I want to diplay a small png image on the top-left of it.

So I used the static file.

In my `mysite` folder I created a folder called `static_files`. In this folder, I added my png image with the name `logo.png`

The I changed my `settings.py` of `mysite`as follows:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static_files/')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My `base.html` contains:

```
    {% load staticfiles %}

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a href="">
  <img src="{static 'logo.png'}" alt="" class="d-inline-block alight-top"/>
  </a>
  <a class="" href="fdklsmflds">Login</a>
  <a class="" href="fdklsmflds">Sign up</a>
</nav>
```

I finally run `python3.6 manage.py collectstatic`

BUT I GET THE ERROR:

```
[04/Jul/2019 18:13:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1379
Not Found: /{static 'logo.png'}
[04/Jul/2019 18:13:54] "GET /%7Bstatic%20'logo.png'%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2139
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `%` symbols to indicate that Djangos template engine should replace that part with the correct content.

Change this part

```
<img src="{static 'logo.png'}" ...
```

to

```
<img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this

```
<img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" alt="" class="d-inline-block alight-top"/>
```

More more details [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)